# How do I grant users permission to create hard links (using GPO or registry entries)?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, symlink, hardlink

I'm working in an AD domain with one DC running Windows Server 2012 R2, and clients running mostly Windows 7 Professional.

**I need to be able to grant certain user groups the permission to create hard links, hopefully via `mklink /H SINK SOURCE`.**

I've already found a GPO which grants the permission to create soft links (that is, to run `mklink SINK SOURCE`) - for reference it's at `Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Create symbolic links` - but I need to be able to set the equivalent policy for hard links.

A registry entry to achieve the same end would be equally as useful - I can set a GPO to make the appropriate registry changes.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/193632/access-is-denied-error-when-i-mklink-on-windows-7

Comment: @GregAskew It looks as though that answers the question only for soft links - something which I've already covered in my question.

Comment: Creating hard links requires administrator permission, and there is not a builtin Windows right to grant permission to create hard links.

Comment: In Windows 8 and forward however, standard users can create hardlinks without any additional configuration or permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer: after much searching it seems as though it can't be done. Standard users cannot be allowed to create hard links in Windows 7.